# Winium taking more then 5 minutes to identify 1 UI element on a .NET based application

Tags: java, .net, automation, white-framework, winium

I am working on a project to automate .NET based application from an open source tool called Winium. 
While running my script, Winium is taking more then 5 minutes to identify 1 UI element which is not the case when I manually use UI SPY for object identification. I don't know what's the problem is. Any suggestions ?

```
winiumexe=new File("J:\\Winium.Desktop.Driver.exe");
options=new DesktopOptions();   
options.setApplicationPath("J:\\fsim-develop\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\FSim.exe");
service=new WiniumDriverService.Builder().usingDriverExecutable(winiumexe).             usingPort(9999).withVerbose(true).withSilent(false).
                buildDesktopService();
driver=new WiniumDriver(service,options);
driver.findElementById("FX_combo").click();
driver.findElementByName("GBP").click();
```

Above FX_combo element is taking more then 3 minutes to identify and click on this button.

Comment: I use Winium to automate my WPF application and even I have noticed slowness but mostly only on Win 10 OS machines. If I run the scripts on Win 7 OS the execution is fast. What is the operating system on which you run the script. If its Win 10 then can you try and run it on Win 7 OS once.

Comment: working on win 7

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem?